# what happens if number of users is lesser then hatch rate in locust

Tags: load-testing, locust

I am doing load test for an application using Locust , but i need to test my app using a single user , scenario is i have single user using which i need to execute some apis multiple times .
So in locust the 2 parameters are number of users and hatch rate , so in my case what would be the values of these 2 .
if i keep number of users = 1 what should be my hatch rate value ?
and also if number of users =1 and hatch rate = 10 then what does that mean from locust point of view ?

```
from locust_base import LocustBase
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task, between, SequentialTaskSet, events


class LoadTestSummary(LocustBase):

    @task()
    def get_org_summary(self):
        response = self.client.get(url)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception('Failure in org summary call. {}: {}'.format(response.status_code,
                                                                                              response.text))


class TestScenario(HttpUser):
    tasks = [LoadTestSummary]
    wait_time = between(5, 9)
    host = "https://google.com"


users = 1
hatch-rate = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of users is the maximum, and it is not affected by the hatch rate.

If you do for example `locust -u 1 -r 10000`, you will still only get 1 user. In your case you dont need to set hatch rate at all.

Comment: So does that mean if i set u=1 and any value for r and set a time for say 1hour , how will i   know how many requests locust is going to send per sec

Comment: You wont, r has no such relation to throughput. Users loop for the duration of the test, r only controls at what rate they are initially started. If you want, you can use wait_time to make one task iteration to take a certain time https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.wait_time.constant_pacing